# Why can't we just count like regular people?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, site-proposal, private-beta

This site is in beta for zero more days? Then you should nag me about it approximately zero more times.

Seriously. I get it. I'm a programmer, too. But come on — am I the only one who just wants to be normal every once in awhile?

[image]

Comment: What's normal??

Comment: +0, good catch!

Comment: It's the Stack Exchange network, the place where *programmers* answer you cooking/... questions! What else would anyone expect than counting from zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I'm adding +1 to this number to ensure it's never zero.

Always underpromise and overdeliver, I say.